# Convert Pandas DataFrame into Series with multiIndex

Tags: pandas, type-conversion

Let us consider a pandas DataFrame (df) like the one shown above.

[image]

How do I convert it to a pandas Series?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just select the single column of your frame

```
df['Count']
```

Answer (score 0):

result = pd.Series(df['Count'])